# Rails pipets assline and YUI

Tags: ruby-on-rails, yui, assets

Does anyone know how to use YUI with Rails? If I call,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css">
```

it works. BUT if I use my own folder and do something like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../../vendor/yui/build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css">
```

it does NOT work. These files, css and js, will not communicate with each other if dissected from their folders and placed adjacently under app/assets, the way Rails requires. I don't care about compressing and minimizing anything. I just want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

In your `application.html.erb` layout

`<%=stylesheet_link-tag "vendor/yui/build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu.css"%>`

One more suggestion is that please use `app/assets/stylesheets` folder put your `menu.css` there

and simply in your `application` layout

`<%=stylesheet_link-tag "menu.css" %>`

Comment: Thank you. But the files must remain in their native folder tree structure, or the buttons do not work right. And the stylesheet_link_tag only works on short directories. I'll use the yahoo site for css. After my presentation, I'll rewrite the site in Java. Besides, I'm tired of having to create empty erb templates to satisfy Rails REST requirements.

Comment: By the way, your solution was good. I had made a mistake, as you can see above, using vendor/yui, when I needed vendor/assets/yui. Makes a difference!

Answer (score 0):

My solution was, in application.css,

```
*= require ../../../vendor/assets/yui/build/reset-fonts-grids/reset-fonts-grids
*= require ../../../vendor/assets/yui/build/menu/assets/skins/sam/menu
```

In application.js,

```
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/yui/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/yui/build/container/container_core
//= require ../../../vendor/assets/yui/build/menu/menu
```

And finally in application.html.erb, the layout,

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I had a little trouble with js, enabled only on page refresh. But reinstalling gem 'turbolinks' magically fixed the problem. My files are just as I downloaded from Yahoo, no directory changes, under

```
/vendor/assets/yui
```

I hope nobody took my 'Java' sarcasm too seriously )

Comment: update: Deploying, whether or not i raked assets, resulted in a loss of some css. Testing all this with smaller files, placing everything where it should go, was just as disappointing. Conclusion...set up an external web site for assets and link with "http://...". Rails will not allow clean links to folders within the program, thanks to the 'pipets assline'.